# MySQL STR_TO_DATE again

Tags: mysql

I've been the whole day trying to import a csv to a table without success.

This is the SQL syntax:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './test.csv' 
INTO TABLE desktop_protection_status 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(`Client`, `Computer type`, `Computer`, `IP address`, `Domain`, `Description`, 
 `Group`, `Agent version`, @Installationdate, @LastConnectionDate, `Platform`, 
 `Operating system`, `Exchange Server`, `Updated protection`, 
 `Protection version`, `Updated knowledge`, @Lastupdateon, `Advanced protection`, 
 `File antivirus`, `Mail antivirus`, `Web browsing antivirus`, `Firewall`, 
 `Device Control`, `Web access control`, `Program blocking`, `Anti-Theft`, 
 `Antivirus for Exchange servers`, `Anti-spam for Exchange servers`, 
 `Content Filtering for Exchange servers`, `Isolation status`, 
 `Installation error date`, `Installation error`, `Installation error code`, 
 `Other security products`)
SET `Installation Date` = STR_TO_DATE(@Installationdate, '%Y-%m-%d %T'), 
    `Last Connection Date` = STR_TO_DATE(@LastConnectionDate, '%Y-%m-%d %T'), 
    `Last Update On` = STR_TO_DATE(@Lastupdateon, '%Y-%m-%d %T');
```

And the CSV file i'm trying to load is like this:

```
Client  Computer type   Computer    IP address  Domain  Description Group   Agent version   Installation date   Last connection date    Platform    Operating system    Exchange Server Updated protection  Protection version  Updated knowledge   Last update on  Advanced protection File antivirus  Mail antivirus  Web browsing antivirus  Firewall    Device Control  Web access control  Program blocking    Anti-Theft  Antivirus for Exchange servers  Anti-spam for Exchange servers  Content Filtering for Exchange servers  Isolation status    Installation error date Installation error  Installation error code Other security products
Client  Laptop  Username    192.168.10.1    DOMAIN.COM      All\WorkStations    1.1.02.0000 2019-06-13 12:44:40 2021-05-06 13:28:59 Windows Windows 10  (Version: 2013) (Build: 12042.938)  Not installed   Yes 4.00.00 Yes 2021-05-06 12:50:02 Enabled Enabled Enabled Enabled Disabled    Disabled    Disabled    Disabled    Not available   Not available   Not available   Not available   Not isolated
```

What am i doing wrong?

Oh, sorry:

```
Warnings: 6048

Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1048): Column 'Installation date' cannot be null
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1048): Column 'Last connection date' cannot be null
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1048): Column 'Last update on' cannot be null
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: "without success" is not a problem description... what should happen? what happens instead? be specific. [edit] to include enough info needed to understand your problem.

Comment: `What am i doing wrong?` ... the answer to this question begins with you telling us what the current error message is.

Comment: After unsucessful import, but in the same connection - check the values of the variables. Does they are really empty?

Comment: Dates are 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem. But all data, including the dates, was imported correctly...

Comment: *original csv is in unicode, after converting it to UTF8 it works like a charm.* [LOAD DATA Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) allows to specify *`[CHARACTER SET charset_name]`* import option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think the reason it doesn't works is because original csv file is unicode, after converting it to UTF8 it seems to work (i have to do some more tests).

Is there any way to load it without converting it to UTF8?

Besides that, original date is mysql standard date format, there's no need to convert it.